# Apache Ant 1.6.5 - Clean Up Unused Jars Files

Tags: ant, jar

I searched the forum before posting.But I could find a suitable answer.

We are using Apache Ant 1.6.5 to build our Java Enterprise Application.We are using lot of external jar files to compile & build the application.I want to clean up the unused jar files.

Is the a easy way to identify & remove the unused jars?.

Comment: Look at http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ or switch to Maven. I recommend Maven.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell In fairness I think the author is trying to identify the 3rd party dependencies rather than manage them.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor I completely understand what he is trying to do. Was only suggesting that an easy way to identify the ones you are using is to use a management tool like Ivy or Maven.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell Completely agree.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [tattletale](http://www.jboss.org/tattletale) tool from Jboss.